# How to convert to array with float values

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

I've been recording audio using the following code

```
bytes = 1024
format = pyaudio.paInt16
channels = 1
outputFile = "C:/python27/test.wav"
rate = 12000
audioRecorder = pyaudio.PyAudio()
recorder = audioRecorder.open(format = format, channels = channels, rate = rate, input = True, frames_per_buffer = bytes)

for i in range(0, int(rate/bytes * duration)):
    data = recorder.read(bytes)
    myArr.append(data)

recorder.stop_stream()
recorder.close()
audioRecorder.terminate()

myArr
```

What kind of datatype is "myArr" and how do I convert it to an array with float values?

EDIT-------------------------------------------------------------------

I've figured out that "myArr" is some sort of a list that looks like this

```
 00: [b'\x01\x00\x04.....
 01: [b'\x01\x00\xfb.....
```

But I want it as an array with single float values. I've been trying to use numpy.array but I cant manage to solve my problem

Comment: Do `print(type(myArr))`

Comment: @azro So I've figured out that "myArr" is a list. I'm trying to use nump.array(myArr) to create an array but i does not create the type of array I need. It is not giving float values in 00, 01, 02, 03..... but instead giving "<bytes_, len() = 2047, bytes_, len() = 2047.....

Comment: Are you sure your recording device is supposed to return float values?

Comment: Yes, I have a code where I create a sine wave and the array im using to play the audio from the sine wave is a bunch of floatvalues

Answer (score 0):

The variable my myArr is a bytes array. You can convert it using

```
Myarr2 = []  
for arr in Myarr:
   content = int.from_bytes(arr, byteorder='big')
   Myarr2.append(content)
```

It takes each value and then converts it back to an integer. If you want to use unsigned integers then change

```
content = int.from_bytes(arr, byteorder='big')
```

to

```
content = int.from_bytes(arr, byteorder='big', signed=False)
```

Comment: and how to I continue this code if I want to convert the int values to floats?